# sql query what is 'C' in this query

Tags: sql

```
select
    C.CMPNAME,
    C.MINBIDVALUE,
    C.PRJID,
    C.ALLOTDATE
from
(
    select
        min(A.bidvalue) as MINBIDVALUE,
        A.prjid,
        P.allotdate,
        A.cmpname
    from
        alloted A,
        projects P
    where
        A.prjid = P.projectid
    group by
        prjid
) C
```

what 'C' (i know it being used as alias but it doesn't have table name declared for it ).
->here A is begin use as alias for alloted n P is begin used for project.

Comment: The whole inner query is `C`.

Answer (score 4):

C is an alias for the results from the sub-query (select min(A.bidvalue) as ....).
This subquery will product a result set which behaves like a table for the duration of the query.  To refer to this result set and its columns, it was given the alias name "C" and all C.stuff are the columns from the sub-query.

Answer (score 3):

It's a subquery. Subqueries are anonymous so they must be given an alias using the `AS` keyword. SQL does allow the `AS` keyword to be omitted.

In this particular query the subquery adds no utility: the inner subquery could be used directly after rearranging the columns to match the outer query.

Comment: `C` is the **alias** of / for that subquery - not that subquery itself, really...

Answer (score 0):

'C' is the alias for the 'result set' of the sub-query defined by

```
select
    min(A.bidvalue) as MINBIDVALUE,
    A.prjid,
    P.allotdate,
    A.cmpname
from
    alloted A,
    projects P
where
    A.prjid = P.projectid
group by
    prjid
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery

```
select
        min(A.bidvalue) as MINBIDVALUE,
        A.prjid,
        P.allotdate,
        A.cmpname
    from
        alloted A,
        projects P
    where
        A.prjid = P.projectid
    group by
        prjid
```

is aliased as "C".